# Large files failing to download using readfile()

Tags: php, download

I have the following code to force download an IPA file (after codesigning it with a script). It works fine with smaller files but with larger files, my web server starts returning a 500 Internal Server Error. Would someone be able to help me tweak my existing code to overcome this issue?

```
$time = md5(time());

// Runs code signing script here
// And then attempts to initiate download

$path = "done/$time/";         
$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';    

$d = dir($path);
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
  if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
    $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
    $latest_filename = $entry;
  }
}        

 header("Cache-Control: public");
 header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$time.ipa");
 header("Content-Type: application/ipa");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
 // Read the file from disk
 readfile("done/$time/".$latest_filename);
       // header('location: dashboard.php');
   } else {
// Throwback

die("Failed. Contact support. // <p>$sign</p>");

}
```

Comment: Maybe your script times out ? The default timeout is 30  seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
$filepath = "done/{$time}/{$latest_filename}";
$size     = filesize($filepath);
$mimetype = 'application/ipa';

// Turn off buffering
if (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}

$handle = fopen($filepath, 'rb');
if ($handle !== false && $size > 0) {
    @flock($handle, LOCK_SH);

    $filename               = rawurldecode($filepath);
    $old_max_execution_time = ini_get('max_execution_time');
    $old_cache_limiter      = session_cache_limiter();

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
    session_cache_limiter(false);

    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header('Content-Type: ' . $mimetype);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'. $filename .'"');
    // or your variant
    // header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . md5(time()));

    header("Content-Length: $size");

    $start = 0;
    $end   = $size - 1;
    $chunk = 8 * 1024;

    $requested  = (float)$end - (float)$start + 1;

    while (! $error) {
        if ($chunk >= $requested) {
            $chunk = (integer)$requested;
        }

        set_time_limit(0);

        while (! feof($handle) && (connection_status() === 0)) {
            if (! $buffer = @fread($handle, $chunk)) {
                $error = true;
                break 2;
            }

            print($buffer);
            flush();
        }

        @flock($handle, LOCK_UN);
        @fclose($handle);

        ini_set('max_execution_time', $old_max_execution_time);
        session_cache_limiter($old_cache_limiter);
        break;
    }

    if ($error) {
        // 500 - Internal server error
        exit;
    }
} else {
    // Can't open file
    exit;
}
```

Comment: After my edit of the incorrect variable, this code works well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem in script time execution.
Try to set `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`
Also try to read and send file by chunks.

Comment: I can confirm that the script I am running isn't timing out since the outputted file (the codesigned IPA) is being saved at the specified location. It is an issue with imitating the download, would you be able to provide a solution with code that I could attempt to use?